# How to set a single root for all CLion includes?

Tags: c++, clion

My CLion project is organized as follows:

```
main.cpp
foo/bar.h
foo/blah.h
```

`main.cpp` has the line `#include "foo/bar.h"` and the latter is located all right.

But `foo/bar.h` has the line `#include "foo/blah.h"` (note the directory name is not omitted, even though both files happen to be in the same directory).

The [FAQ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/) suggests that a solution to "*CLion fails to find some of my headers. Where does it search for them?*" is to add the line

```
set(INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES .)
```

to `CMakeLists.txt`. This vibes as just the right answer since it matches what we'd do on the command line (add the flag `-I.`), but that doesn't help.

How do I tell CLion that I would like all includes to be relative to a single root?

Related question(s):

- [Tell CLion to use header include path with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619898/tell-clion-to-use-header-include-path-with-prefix)

Comment: Show us how u include them, by default you haven't to add include_directories(foo)

Comment: @jamek Done. Added the `#include` lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple way to do it is this:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

If you want to dictate include paths for interfaces or installations (e.g. you're writing a library to be imported by other projects) then have a look at the documentation for

```
target_include_directories(...)
```